# Working with 2 apps in PhpStorm not lose current session options

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm 2019.2.3 I work with 2 @vue/cli and Laravel 6 Backend REST API applications
and have to switch from one app to another. Can I set hot keys for selecting another app 
or automate it in someway?

Also I lose some current session options , like current Search Scope/find options in top left 
and I would like to avoid it and keep them...

If there is a way ?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I got the issues you are having. Regarding the shortcut for switching, why doesn't Alt+Tab work for you, am I missing something? Or, there's a designated shortcut for switching between projects, Window | Next/Previous Project window. As for losing options, could you please be more specific? I can't reproduce that locally, Find in Path remembers its setup when I switch between projects

Comment: No  Alt+Tab , I mean in PhpStorm to close / reopen 2 apps I work on. Sorry, if I put it unclear.

Comment: I once again not sure if I understood you right, but let me try - if you have `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Reopen last project on startup` enabled, and close PhpStorm with `File | Exit` (or `Cmd+Q` on macOS), when you start PhpStorm again, it'll reopen all projects, not only the last focused one. Or did I get you wrong this time as well?